# Torch nn. Current error always is nan

Tags: torch

I've wrote the following code:

```
require 'nn'
require 'cunn'

file = torch.DiskFile('train200.data', 'r')
size = file:readInt()
inputSize = file:readInt()
outputSize = file:readInt()

dataset = {}

function dataset:size() return size end;

for i=1,dataset:size() do
  local input = torch.Tensor(inputSize)
  for j=1,inputSize do
    input[j] = file:readFloat()
  end
  local output = torch.Tensor(outputSize)
  for j=1,outputSize do
    output[j] = file:readFloat()
  end
  dataset[i] = {input:cuda(), output:cuda()}
end

net = nn.Sequential()

hiddenSize = inputSize * 2

net:add(nn.Linear(inputSize, hiddenSize))
net:add(nn.Tanh())
net:add(nn.Linear(hiddenSize, hiddenSize))
net:add(nn.Tanh())
net:add(nn.Linear(hiddenSize, outputSize))

criterion = nn.MSECriterion()

net = net:cuda()
criterion = criterion:cuda()

trainer = nn.StochasticGradient(net, criterion)
trainer.learningRate = 0.02
trainer.maxIteration = 100

trainer:train(dataset)
```

And it must works good (At least I think so), and it works correct when `inputSize = 20`. But when `inputSize = 200` current error always is `nan`. At first I've thought that file reading part is incorrect. I've recheck it some times but it is working great. Also I found that sometimes too small or too big learning rate may affect on it. I've tried learning rate from 0.00001 up to 0.8, but still the same result. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: Please include the full error message and your output from comparable runs, such as which learning rates do and do not change the result.

Comment: There's no errors. I have just the following output `# current error = nan`